# Testing if custom exception was thrown when a run time exception is thrown using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito

I have this code where I'm catching some exception and throwing a custom exception instead.

```
@Override
public void config() throws CustomException{
    File jsonFile = new File("config.json");
    try {
        ConfigMapper config = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, ConfigMapper.class);

        try {
            this.instanceId = Integer.parseInt(config.getConfig().getClientId());
            this.configParams = config.getConfig().getConfigParams();

        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            throw new CustomException("Please provide a valid integer for instance ID", ex);
            //LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "error initializing instanceId. Should be an integer " + e);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new CustomException("Error trying to read/write", ex);
        // LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException while processing the received init config params", e);
    }
}
```

I need to write a unit test for this and below is how I wrote it.

```
 @Test
public void should_throw_exception_when_invalid_integer_is_given_for_instanceID(){
    boolean isExceptionThrown = false;
    try{
        Mockito.doThrow(new NumberFormatException()).when(objectMock).config();
        barcodeScannerServiceMock.config();
    } catch (CustomException ex) {
        isExceptionThrown = true;
    }
    assertTrue(isExceptionThrown);
}
```

But its throwing a number format exception and not the CustomException as I want it to be. But this makes sense as I'm using the mock object to throw the exception as a result of which my code logic is not executed. But if that's the case, how do I test this scenario? Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

1.) Remove the line `Mockito.doThrow(new NumberFormatException()).when(objectMock).config();`

2.) Change the Client-ID in your JSON-File to something that cannot be converted to an Integer.

`this.instanceId = Integer.parseInt(config.getConfig().getClientId());` will fail due to that and thus throw an exception.

One advice regarding names: The name of your test method should be what's written in the Java-Doc. Just name it "testCustomException" & explain the methods function in the Java-Documentation. There are **Naming-Conventions** in Java (click [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)) which are basically general guidelines.

Practicing these is very helpful as it allows you to quickly get into your code again after not working on it for a month or so due to the increased readability.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more on your advice for naming- `testCustomException` tells you nothing.  The name the OP currently has is pretty much spot on

Comment: @MrWiggles You do know that Java has naming conventions, right? Not only is it highly recommended to use **short, clear names** to indicate the purpose of the method, but also to use uppercase letters for new words instead of underlines.

Comment: you do know I've written a book on good unit testing practises, right?

Comment: @Seth shouldn't we able to test our code without making changes in it? Currently that instanceId is a private variable. So I can't change it and call the method just for testing purposes right? Are there any alternatives to this? Using mocking or some other feature?

Comment: @MrWiggles shouldn't we able to test our code without making changes in it? Currently that instanceId is a private variable. So I can't change it and call the method just for testing purposes right? Are there any alternatives to this? Using mocking or some other feature?

Comment: There's no reason to use mocking here, or to change your production code - @Seth has described a viable solution to solving your problem

Comment: @MrWiggles I did in fact not know that, but that name is no good practice, even if it's just because of the "_". I guess the readability does not really matter in tests (since they're in most cases small enough to be readable regardless of the naming), but still, I'd highly recommend sticking with the conventions.

Comment: I'm not fussed about _ vs camelCase but a test name should describe behaviour and outcome not just be `testCustomException` as it gives no information at all.  There's also no need to have `test` at the beginning of a test name.  A good guidleline is to think of class name + test name as a human readable sentence describing specifications